# Adding symbol to external names directory of static library

Tags: ios, static-libraries, undefined-reference, otool, nm

I am confused by the difference in the symbol lists produced by `otool` and `nm` for a particular static library. I am trying to link a few static libraries to create the final executable but the linker is complaining that `Undefined symbols:  "_main", referenced from: _main$non_lazy_ptr in crt1.o`. If I do `nm` on one of the libraries (`libext.a`), I see that `_main` is defined in a file called `main.o`. but if I do a `otool-s` on thesame library I see that `_main` is not present in the `__.SYMDEF` section of the archive. How do I force `_main` to be included in this section? Doing `ranlib -c` on the library does not help.